# The complexity of the following code is O(n) , but if arr [ i ] < arr [ j ] is changed as arr [ i ] < = arr [ j ], Still the complexity remain same?

Tags: algorithm, performance, loops, time-complexity, big-o

```
void fun(int n, int arr[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(; i < n; ++i)
        while(j < n && arr[i] < arr[j])
            j++;
}
```

If arr[i] < arr[j] is changed as arr[i] < = arr[j], Time Complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Both answers have the same running time `O(n)`, regardless of whether `arr[i] < arr[j]` or `arr[i] <= arr[j]`, since `i` counter only increase `n` times and `while loop` condition is true at most `n`times because `j` is increased at most `n` times (refer to `j < n`).